# Should I really use localhost when opening MySQL database from PHP?

Tags: php, ios, mysql

I am trying to connect my iOS device to my localhost mysql server on my mac. I tested some basic html style signup/ login functionality and got it to work meaning my server works. How would I set the following `mysqli_connect` statement from this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12#comments ?

```
//update to http://http://192.168.0.5

$link = mysqli_connect("http://192.168.0.5","root","root");
mysqli_select_db($link, "databasename");
```

I can't use 'localhost' because I was told my iPad would "try to connect to itself" at run time. When i try to get my current DHCP via

```
ipconfig getifaddr en1
```

from my mac terminal, I get one but it just doesn't feel right as I can't connect to 192.168.0.5 from my safari address bar.

Does anyone know any suggestions? Quite frankly the application stack in the latter link is kicking my ass. Luckily it's available for download.

```
//updated to kAPIHost @"http://192.168.0.5" 

#define kAPIHost @"http://192.168.0.5" 
#define kAPIPath @"iReporter/"
```

I need help setting the above line...Should it be path formatted like above or an IP? Still getting an error.

Would the '#define kAPIHost @"http://XX.XX.XX.XXX/folder/"' path style format be better for kAPIPath? I seem to be trouble accessing this folder in general...

Comment: By the way, while that article might be a good primer on the topic, it engages in one extremely dangerous practice, namely writing PHP code that just takes request parameters and directly uses them in SQL strings. That makes this code susceptible to SQL injection attacks. You really have to escape with [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or bind values to `?` placeholders in your SQL. Don't worry about it right now, but before you put this on public server, research that topic thoroughly.

Comment: I know what you mean. well said and dearly noted. I planed for a while on making some tweaks to the parameters you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

This PHP code is running on the web server that your iOS app is connecting to (this code is *not* running in the iOS device, itself), so `localhost` is fine.

This iOS device does, though, need to interact with the web service, though, so as you write your `NSURLConnection`, `NSURLSession`, or AFNetworking code, that's where you need to worry about the IP address or name of the web service. (And, if connecting via WiFi, you could temporarily use the IP number or name of your computer that you see in the "sharing" section in the Mac's system preferences. If connecting via cellular, it's more complicated.)

---

In your revised question, you reference a host variable. That's where you supply your IP number:

```
#define kAPIHost @"http://192.168.0.5/folder/"
```

Frankly, that should make you as queasy as the idea of using a fixed IP number in your PHP code, but this is just something you're using during your development.

If you go to your computer's "system preferences" and look at "sharing", it will give you a name you could use here, instead. For example, mine is:

```
#define kAPIHost @"http://Robs-iMac.local/folder/"
```

Yours will differ, but you get the idea. Of course, replace "folder" and `kAPIPath` with the appropriate values.

And remember, this only works if your iOS device is connecting via wifi. To connect remotely is more complicated, and frankly when you get to that point, you might just want to invest in some web hosting service, and move your PHP code onto that ISP's servers.

Comment: Ok, the application uses AFNetworking and NSUrl to call the variables kAPIhost and kAPIPath to reference the correct ip address etc

Comment: Yep, so just your you computer's IP number or its name in that host constant. But don't worry about the use of `localhost` in the PHP.

Comment: using 'ipconfig getifaddr en1' from the terminal and set the paramaters accordingly *update above

Comment: i agree with the queasiness and yes this is just for development

Comment: Don't worry about that stuff. I was just showing you how to get that local subnet address. And you don't need to worry about this if you don't want. Just use the IP nunber if you want, but realize that number may change (esp if you reboot your machine). But no need to get lost in the intricacies of networking at this point. Just get your web service working first.

Comment: could i set the bottom string to an empty string ("") this is what's said about those two statements;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66486/discussion-between-rob-and-godman).